# How can you draw exact lengths in inches using DPI on Android devices properly?

Tags: java, android, dpi

Currently I measure the devices DPI, then draw a line at a certain number of pixels based on DPI (if the DPI is 320, then I display a line every 320 pixels).

I have it working on some devices, but then others are way off which has left me very confused...

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Heres the code I used to get the devices DPI (among other various things)

```
    metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;
    xdpi = metrics.xdpi;
    ydpi = metrics.ydpi;
    densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
```

Then heres how I am drawing the lines across the top of the screen.

```
    x = 0;
    while (x <= width) {
        canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, lineHeight, paint);
        x = x + xdpi;
    }
```

At first I was using the variable densityDpi to draw the lines, but then I found out thats only an estimated DPI. So I changed the code to xdpi which is supposed to be based on the screens actual pixels however its still not accurate on some devices.

Comment: I'd find it more surprising if you have it working on every Android out there. It's possible the X and Y DPIs differ too. The only reliable but possibly unfeasible way I can think of is to have your own DB with DPIs. Another option would be to let the user calibrate by letting them use a credit card as a measure.

Comment: This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0) confirms the answers so far: there is no reliable way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, needed to draw a coin in the exact size it is in real life. Each device should report it's proper DPI, but some (few) devices just provide wrong data. I ended up allowing users to resize the image manually.